# Why the file cannot be save properly?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, excel

the client browser get excel filer from the server and adownload to the loacal machine.

Here is the code on server side that sends response to the client:

```
     public ActionResult GetExcel(int month, int year)
    {
        var workbook = CreateWorkSheet1.WriteExcelWithNPOI();
        using (var exportData = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            Response.Clear();
            workbook.Write(exportData);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "ContactNPOI.xlsx"));
            Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.ToArray());
            Response.End();
        }

        return View(workbook);
    }
```

And here is my javascript code on client side that get result from server method above:

```
    $scope.downloadFile = function(){
        return $http.get("../WsAvivim/SaveToClientDepartmentRepotr/GetExcel?" + "year=" + $scope.year + "&month=" + $scope.month).then(function (response) {
            var f = response.data;
            var ref = document.createElement("a");
            ref.href = "data:" + f.ContentType + ";base64," + f.FileContents;
            ref.download = f.FileDownloadName;
            ref.click();

        });
```

As you can see in example above javascript get result from server and try to save excel file.The file is saved.

But when it's saved on the browser it's looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in image above something was wrong and file cannot be opened.

Any idea what wrong with my code?why the file cannot be save properly?

Comment: Why don't you just download the normal way instead of going first into a data URL?

Comment: Crowcoder, thanks for post.can you post example?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an example handy.

Comment: just call the action method directly from a hyperlink and it'll trigger the download automatically. Doing it via ajax and then spoofing a hyperlink is a bizarre layer of indirection. Downloads via ajax are problematic at the best of times. Also `return View(workbook);` makes no sense and is redundant, since you already ended the response on the previous line - this code will never execute, and wouldn't work if you did. Also consider using FileResult instead of the older-style code you've got there, it should handle things more neatly.